# Sharepoint basic textbook

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to teach SharePoint myself. However, I just have some knowledge of ASP.NET development. With that knowledge can I pick up sharepoint and handle projects?
Can someone recommend good textbooks and online resources to learn sharepoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having .NET development experience will not let you just handle projects inside Sharepoint.  There is an entire ecosystem that exists inside SP: governance, administration, usage, evangelism, etc.  Being a developer, you think in terms of software and can probably pick things up quicker than most.  But until you've been through the right of passage that is Sharepoint consulting, your opinions will always be based on what you can read online, which in many instances is not enough for your situation.  Sharepoint is a platform, not a solution in and of itself.  It requires knowing how the application works, yes, but that isn't enough.  You can accomplish the same thing many different ways and often times, they can all be right.  It is a matter of a knowing the long term consequences of each one of those methods that makes one 'know' Sharepoint.  It also requires you to listen to users like you've never listened to them before.  Many solutions are technically right in Sharepoint, but good luck getting end users to actually use them.  User coaching will be a huge skill that you'll end up picking up.  I liken Sharepoint to Drupal, SAP, or Wordpress in that many people get the same result but by different roads.  Your development knowledge of Sharepoint is only useful when you've exhausted your out of the box options that Sharepoint provides.  Going into any problem with the mindset of custom code inside Sharepoint will eventually get you many, many headaches.